# Can Ajax CalendarExtender have Boundfield as the TargetControlID

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

Can Ajax CalendarExtender have asp:BoundField as the TragetControlID because in the grid i have, it says unavailable. How can i get each date from the calendar into the BoundField?

```
<asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="center" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Middle" FooterStyle-Width="25px" HeaderText="Schedule">
                <ItemTemplate>
         <asp:ImageButton ID="CalendarIcon" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/calender-no-edit.gif" />&nbsp;
               <ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender1" runat="server" PopupPosition="Left" PopupButtonID="CalendarIcon"
                    TargetControlID="ScheduleDate" >
                </ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="ScheduleDate" HeaderText="Deal"><HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" /></asp:BoundField>
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Check out this thread on the asp.net forums: [Ajax Calendar Extender Within Gridview](http://forums.asp.net/p/1236551/2246294.aspx)